# Increase counter upon change of value

Tags: r

I made a function to increase a counter whenever the value in a vector changes:

```
track_change = function(x) {
  counter = numeric(length(x))
  for (i in seq_along(x)) {
    if (i > 1 && x[i] != x[i-1])
      counter[i] = counter[i-1] + 1
    else if (i > 1)
      counter[i] = counter[i-1]
  }
  counter
}
```

Example (see how `track` changes upon every change of `carb`):

```
mtcars$track = track_change(mtcars$carb)

head(mtcars[, 10:12])
                  gear carb track
Mazda RX4            4    4     0
Mazda RX4 Wag        4    4     0
Datsun 710           4    1     1
Hornet 4 Drive       3    1     1
Hornet Sportabout    3    2     2
Valiant              3    1     3
```

Is there a better way to do this in R? (It should also be able to track changes in non-numerical vectors, incl. lists.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can do this with `rleid` from `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
rleid(mtcars$carb)-1
```

---

Or with `rle` from `base R`

```
inverse.rle(within.list(rle(mtcars$carb), values <- seq_along(values))) - 1
```

Comment: Thanks. The `for loop` solution is actually about 5-10% faster than `rle` approach on my data (just FYI).

Comment: @jakub I would say that you should check the benchmarks on a bigger dataset i.e. around a million or more datapoints