# How to get the rows of a dataframe together (selcted row bottom up)

Tags: r, dataframe

I explain my question with an example. For example, if I am in the row number 5 (following table), how can I get the rows before 5 that have the same `P_P` value. The point is the row index of the selected rows should be sequential.
For example in the case of following table, I need to get only rows 3 and 4 (since between the row 1 and the rest of the rows there is row number 2 with different `P_P`.)
FYI, I could use `for loop` to do it but I want to avoid it.

Thanks

```
ID   Contest   P_P   Time
1      UMA      A    2015
2      DOIS     B    2016
3      DOIS     A    2016
4      UMA      A    2017
5      DOIS     A    2017
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41535081/increase-counter-upon-change-of-value http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29661269/increment-by-1-for-every-change-in-column-in-r ... and then subsetting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do this in `base` R:

```
rw <- 5
df[(max(which(!(df[1:(rw-1),]$P_P==df[rw,]$P_P)))+1):(rw-1),]

# ID Contest P_P Time
#3  3    DOIS   A 2016
#4  4     UMA   A 2017
```

The idea is to first find matches between 1 through `rw-1` (i.e., `df[1:(rw-1),]$P_P==df[rw,]$P_P`) and then find the last non-match (i.e., `FALSE`) which is captured by `max(which(!...))`.

---

```
df <- structure(list(ID = 1:5, Contest = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L), .Label = c("DOIS", "UMA"), class = "factor"), P_P = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("A", "B"), class = "factor"), Time = c(2015L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2017L, 2017L)), .Names = c("ID", "Contest", "P_P", 
"Time"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
row <- 5

## get the subset with P_P = p-p of row 
subset <- subset(df[(row-1):1,], P_P == df[row,]$P_P)

## check the difference 
a <- which(abs(diff(subset$ID)) != 1)


subset[1:a[1],]

# ID Contest P_P Time
# 4  4     UMA   A 2017
# 3  3    DOIS   A 2016
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution with `rev()` and `rle()`:

```
tail(d, rle(rev(as.integer(d$P_P)))$lengths[1]) # with last row
head(tail(d, rle(rev(as.integer(d$P_P)))$lengths[1]), -1) # without last row
```

Another solution:
We can use `inverse.rle()` to build a grouping variable:

```
r <- rle(as.character(d$P_P)) # also possible: r <- rle(as.integer(d$P_P))
r$values <- seq(r$values)
d$group <- inverse.rle(r)
i <- 5
d[d$group==d$group[i],]
```

result:

```
#  ID Contest P_P Time group
#3  3    DOIS   A 2016     3
#4  4     UMA   A 2017     3
#5  5    DOIS   A 2017     3
```

If you want a result without the row `i`:

```
subset(d[-i,], group==d$group[i])
```

data:

```
d <- structure(list(ID = 1:5, Contest = structure(c(2L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 
1L), .Label = c("DOIS", "UMA"), class = "factor"), P_P = structure(c(1L, 
2L, 1L, 1L, 1L), .Label = c("A", "B"), class = "factor"), Time = c(2015L, 
2016L, 2016L, 2017L, 2017L)), .Names = c("ID", "Contest", "P_P", 
"Time"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```